# How to write a collection layout just like the IOS app task list switching screen?

Tags: ios, layout, coverflow

I know there is a lot of coverflow layout on github, but the animation is different.

[image: coverflow]
[image: ios]

Comment: It seem to be appropriate with your purpose:
https://cocoapods.org/?q=icarousel

Comment: iCarousel, thanks, I'll check it out